# JSON в C# and C++: nlohmann VS newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, c++, json, json.net

Господа, вопрос адресуется тем, кто лучше меня знает возможности библиотеки newtonsoft.json.

В общем, я на С++ c json (а именно, с nlohmann json) работал немножко больше, и привык к тому, что если у меня в коде есть

```
    json j;
```

то я могу писать такие прирятные выражения, как

```
    auto certAuth = j["certificationAuthority"];
    if ( !certAuth.empty() ){ ... }
```

- то есть, здесь я беру часть json - файла по ключу, а) не задумываюсь о том, есть такой ключ или нети б) когда я что то взял по ключу - это тоже json и с ним можно продолжать работать как с json

Если я хочу проверить, что такой ключ есть - у меня есть метод `.at()`

Кроме того, я могу делать операции со вложенными json - элементами, типа

```
    if ( ! j["applicant"].at("shortName").is_null() )
            shortName = j["applicant"]["shortName"];
```

Кроме того, у меня есть итераторы для обхода списка, например,

```
    j["applicant"].begin()
```

И всё это - я делаю без необходимости десериализации json в какой то другой тип, что довольно удобно в моём случае: *мне приходит большой json - документ, а нужна оттуда всего пара полей.*

Но у меня есть старый код, написанный на C#, и там используется newtonsoft.json. А его я знаю хуже. И сразу переписать этот код я не могу, но там надо провернуть очень похожую операцию: есть большой json-документ со сложной структурой, а нужна оттуда всего пара полей. Путь к которым я знаю.

Но все примеры с newtonsoft, которые мне попадались, основаны были на том, что мы сначала с json - строкой (файлом, потоком и т.п.) делаем JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(), а потом уже работаем со свойствами десериализованного объекта.

Не подскажете ли мне, есть ли в C# возможность работать с json более нативно, примерно как это позволяет nlohmann? То есть, буквально, как "доступаться по ключу", проверять существование ключа в json и итерироваться по коллекции?

Возможно, все это есть либо в newtonsoft, либо в каком то другом месте, и я просто плохо искал.

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: В C# аналогично можно работать с JSON без десериализации. В библиотеке newtonsoft для этого предназначены классы `JObject` и `JArray`.

Comment: А в модном `System.Text.Json` есть класс `Utf8JsonReader` - [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63670028/12888024) я с ним игрался.

Comment: Насколько я помню, что еще в `Newtonsoft.Json` можно десереализовать в `dynamic`. `dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(...)`, и обращаться к полям типа `data["certificationAuthority"]`. Но деды C# не советуют этот способ, потому что можно легко накосячить или все сломается при изменении структуры JSON.

Comment: *"Возможно, все это есть либо в newtonsoft, либо в каком то другом месте, и я просто плохо искал."* - тут скорее *"совсем не искал"*, это все описано в документации...

Comment: `без необходимости десериализации json в какой то другой тип, что довольно удобно в моём случае` - а как большой документ относится к удобству и прочему? Наоборот, когда вы десериализуете, вы пишете и кода меньше и бережете себя от проблем в будущем, ибо если на сервере вдруг поменяется название значений, то вам придется во всем коде менять эти `string` значения, ну и также, вам все эти "ключи" надо держать в голове. Мой вам совет, сделайте десериализацию, а если нужно всего одно значение из тысячи других, то просто класс с 1 свойством, все, этого достаточно, не заполняйте его целиком!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - спасибо, это важное замечание, которое мне не приходило в голову. То есть, создание класса, который "похож" на json - объект - выглядит естественно, когда используется много полей json - объекта, а при работе с парой полей это казалось излишеством. Теперь понятно, что можно просто сделать "очень маленький класс"

Answer (score 0):

Я стал разбираться, и получилось, что я просто не дочитал до нужного места.

Вот так делается то, что я назвал "доступ по ключу"

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm

Ну и дальше в том же духе, сейчас дочитаю и напишу подробный ответ. я просто попал в типичную ловушку: любая документация по newtonsoft начинается с десериализации, и дальше я просто не посмотрел.